# Can I have a REPL but for writing GDI+ code in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, gdi+

Is there any trick to visualize graphically the following GDI code without having to compile => run => stop => edit => compile => run?

```
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;    
g.DrawImage(Logo, x, y, _commonProfile.WidthImm, _commonProfile.HeightIntes);
font = new Font("Arial", _commonProfile.FontSizeIntes, FontStyle.Bold);
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Far;
g.DrawString(Settings.testo_D_sup, font, brush, new RectangleF(x, y, _commonProfile.WidthIntes, _commonProfile.HeightIntes), format);
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
```

Comment: ps: I am pretty sure the question will be downvoted, because many developers see the missing features of an IDE as a challenge to show their ability (instead of realizing that it's also tons of extra work). Compare VS with Revit, Autocad or 3DStudio to have an idea of what other software offer to their users.

Comment: VS is an IDE for writing code it is not a CAD program, your comparison does not make sense.

Comment: The other programs you mention are geared around parsing and displaying that data in a graphical manner.  Do you really want VS to run arbitrary code to see what the result would be?  What if you had a function call in the middle of the code block that takes 10 seconds to run? Or perhaps more malicious code - just opening a project could become dangerous.

Comment: BenRobinson: I can just expose my opinion. A CAD is a software that helps people to write binary code which is interpreted by a machine in a visual way. Imagine the development process to be very more mature. Compare what we call "high level" languages with the parametric objects offered by Revit or 3DStudio max inside their environment.. In revit they call family what we call class. But the editor is doing a lot of work. It's possible to define "groups" of objects. Think how an ide use the space on video.

Comment: JamesThorpe: malicious code can be also in an image. And the whole code world is going from procedural to the MVC approach. We are loosing freedom and getting more powerful tools. That's the benefit of a structured approach.. and I don't see so terrible having the possibility to edit code and see GDI redrawn. I really think that as developers we don't spend so much time wondering why our productivity is slow (compared to graphics).. Our tools are flexible but we loose something.

Comment: Visual Studio DOES have a graphical component. XAML, for example, gets rendered in real time. As for your code, the IDE won't be able to categorize your code and say "oh, this block of code is drawing stuff, I'm just gonna run it without the user's consent". What if you had a line of code somewhere in between that had nothing to do with drawing stuff to the screen (e.g. a call to a database or such). If this reasoning is not obvious to you, you need to read a book or two on how compilers work.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: I like what you wrote, I think this topics could go on and become interesting. I've a 5 years degree in computer science. I understand the complexity of the kind of task I'm suggesting but there are possible solutions. In fact XAML is not the only graphical part, but there is a visual editor also for the windows forms. And it works.. people could put a DB call in the initialization method but this didn't prevented microsoft from doing something that works 90% of the times.

Comment: How about "Add-> New Item->Windows Forms->Custom Control". Open a new form in a designer and drop the custom control there. Then put your code inside control's `OnPaint` and play with it. But you need to press F6 though :-)

Comment: @IvanStoev: thanks! I edited the question and voted to reopen.. That's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method is utilizing the WF project design time support in VS combined with a project level custom control. Use "Add-> New Item->Windows Forms->Custom Control" command to create a new project level custom control. Compile the project and the control will appear in the toolbox. Open a new form in a designer and drop the control there. Now you can put the drawing code inside the control's `OnPaint` method and play with it. The only requirement is to compile the project after making drawing code changes and the form designer will reflect them immediately.

Just keep in mind that this method does not support debugging the drawing code - you can put breakpoints, but they'll never be hit.